# Mockito in Spock

Tags: java, groovy, mockito, spock

Someone can tell me, why this things are not equal?

```
service.getData(any(FindRequest.class), any(Some.class)) >> List.of(new FoundItem("One", new Answer(Map.of("Test", 3))))
Mockito.when(service.getData(any(FindRequest.class), any(Some.class))).thenReturn(List.of(new FoundItem("One", new Answer(Map.of("Test", 3)))))
```

With Mockito mock all works fine, but I need it to work on spock

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at Spock's syntax for [argument constraints](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0-M5/all_in_one.html#_argument_constraints), you are mixing Mockito code with Spock's mocks, so it won't work. ALSO `service` needs to be a mock created by Spock, not a Mockito mock. If you want to use Mockito with Spock, that is possible, but you have to use Mockito for everything, you can't mix them for the same mock.

This is how it should look in Spock's syntax, I've also groovyfied the response with list and map literals.

`service.getData(_ as FindRequest, _ as Some) >> [new FoundItem("One", new Answer(["Test": 3]))]`

If you actually don't care about whether the arguments are instances of a certain type, then you can drop the `as Class` bit.